# Unable to use strongly-typed views when using PagedList.MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

When using only `@model Project.Models.UserModel`, I can use the `TextBoxFor` just fine. But when altering it to `@model PagedList.IPagedList<Project.Models.UserModel>`, I can't use the `TextBoxFor` anymore.

Create.cshtml - I can't use `TextBoxFor` without getting an error.

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Project.Models.UserModel>

...
//I'm having a problem with this code
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.userid)

...
```

> 'IPagedList' does not contain a definition for 'user' and no extension method 'user' accepting a first argument of type 'IPagedList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

UserController.cs - I'm returning a PagedList

```
public ActionResult Create(string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
{
    if (searchString != null)
    {
        page = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        searchString = currentFilter;
    }

    ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;
    var users = from ug in _odb.USR_MSTR
                     select new UserModel
                     {
                         userid = ug.USR_ID,
                         user = ug.USR_DESC,
                         status = (ug.INACTV_DT == null ? "Active" : "Inactive")
                     };

    int pageSize = 10;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

    ViewBag.UserFilter = GetSelectListItems();  

    return View(users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
}

public JsonResult Save_User(UserModel model)
{
    string _message = string.Empty;
    using (var _odb = new ProjectEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            USR_MSTR usr_master = new USR_MSTR();
            usr_master.USER_ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Remove(20);
            usr_master.USER_DESC = model.user;
            usr_master.CREATE_DT = DateTime.Now;

            _odb.USR_MSTR.Add(usr_master);
            _odb.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _message = "An error occured.";
            _message = ex.InnerException.Message;
        }
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

UserModel.cs - all my textboxes are defined here

```
public class UserModel
{
    public string userId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string user { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Status")]
    public string status { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Filter Search By")]
    public int filterSearchBy { get; set; }

    public int filterSearchText { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want both (textbox for new user creation and list of users for the user list), you should create a new viewmodel with those 2 properties

```
public class CreateAndListVm
{
  public string UserId {set;get;}
  public IPagedList<CDS.Models.UserModel> Users {set;get;}
}
```

Now from your Create action, instead of returning the paged list, return an object of this view model. You should load the `Users` property value before returning.

```
var vm = new CreateAndListVm();
vm.Users = users.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
return View(vm);
```

Now your view should be strongly typed to this new view model. You can use `Model.Users` property to render the list of users.

```
@model CreateAndListVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
   <label>New User Id</label>
   @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.UserId)
   <input type="submit" />
}
<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.Users)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.UserId</td>                     
    </tr>
}    
</table>
```

Comment: Hi Shyju, thanks for the reply! It really helped me a lot figuring out what ViewModels are really for. I also added in my question my `Model` class and `JsonResult` method in `Controller` class. This is because I'm quite confused with your `CreateAndListVm` ViewModel. It has userId. Shouldn't be userId in the `Model`? Coz I got one in my `Model` already

Comment: You can replace userId with whatever property values you need to create a new User.

Comment: Just want to be clear: So the `TextBoxFor` textboxes uses variables defined in the `CreateAndListVM` right? Like the UserId, etc. Then displaying records are done by accessing the `IPagedList<CDS.Models.UserModel> Users` set in `CreateAndListVM`?

Comment: Yes. When you post the form(for creating new record), you can also use the same view model as your parameter and read the UserId/WhateverPropertyNameYouWant value and use that to save to the db.